# not update sms contentprovider database in 2.3

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I  am inserting sms using following

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("address", smsobj.getAddress());
    values.put("body", smsobj.getMsg());
    values.put("date", smsobj.getTime());
    // values.put("_id", cursor.getString(columnId));
    // values.put("thread_id", cursor.getString(columnThreadId));
    values.put("type", smsobj.getFolderName());
    values.put("read", smsobj.getReadState());

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    Uri uri;
    if (smsobj.getFolderName().equals("1")) {
        uri = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
    } else {
        uri = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
    }

    if (uri != null) {


        context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);


    }
```

it inserts sms and display in default sms application perfactly but after than when I query on ContentProvider that inserted thread is not display using following code and important this issue is in android 2.3 and below because in all atest version it works perfactly.

```
Uri message = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations");

cursor = cr.query(message, null, null, null, "date DESC");
```

Suggest me if anyone solved this issue.
Thanks in advance.